# Spring Boot WebClient : Closes connection prematurely before response

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, web

I am trying to learn spring boot Webclient. In order to understand "non-blocking" HTTP requests, I made two spring boot applications

1. **Spring Boot REST API server** : This has a simple REST endpoint with a 10 seconds sleep to hold the request.
2. **REST Client** : A simple (non web) spring boot application which will call the REST API server by using RestTemplate and Webclient. I am using both to visually understand the non blocking behavior.

See the code for the REST API Server

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class UserApi {

    @GetMapping(path = "/test")
    public String test() {
        System.out.println("Test Request Started");

        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Test Request Ended");

        return "OK";
    }

}
```

Code of the REST client

```
public class RestClient{

    public void restTemplate() {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        String string = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8080/api/test", String.class);
        System.out.println(string);
    }

    public void webClient() {
         Mono<String> bodyToMono = WebClient.create("http://localhost:8080/")
                .get()
                .uri("/api/test")
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class);
         bodyToMono.subscribe(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

And I am calling this class from my Spring Boot Main method as

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class WebClientApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WebClientApplication.class, args);
        RestClient restClient = new RestClient();
        System.out.println("Testing with Webclient");
        restClient.webClient();
        System.out.println("Testing with RestTemplate");
        restClient.restTemplate();
    }

}
```

Problem :

I get the following exception which I have no reason :

```
Caused by: reactor.netty.http.client.PrematureCloseException: Connection prematurely closed BEFORE response
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ Request to GET http://localhost:8080/api/test [DefaultWebClient]
Stack trace:
```

If you want to see the detailed log :

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.3.0.RELEASE)

2020-05-16 16:32:17.506  INFO 9928 --- [  restartedMain] c.w.server.client.WebClientApplication   : Starting WebClientApplication on DESKTOP-054O660 with PID 9928 (D:\eclipse-jee-2019-09-R-win32-x86_64\workspace\WebClientDemoServer\client\target\classes started by Akshay in D:\eclipse-jee-2019-09-R-win32-x86_64\workspace\WebClientDemoServer\client)
2020-05-16 16:32:17.506  INFO 9928 --- [  restartedMain] c.w.server.client.WebClientApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-05-16 16:32:17.631  INFO 9928 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2020-05-16 16:32:17.631  INFO 9928 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2020-05-16 16:32:19.004 DEBUG 9928 --- [  restartedMain] reactor.netty.tcp.TcpResources           : [http] resources will use the default LoopResources: DefaultLoopResources {prefix=reactor-http, daemon=true, selectCount=4, workerCount=4}
2020-05-16 16:32:19.007 DEBUG 9928 --- [  restartedMain] reactor.netty.tcp.TcpResources           : [http] resources will use the default ConnectionProvider: reactor.netty.resources.PooledConnectionProvider@6eb63cda
2020-05-16 16:32:19.053  INFO 9928 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2020-05-16 16:32:19.121  INFO 9928 --- [  restartedMain] c.w.server.client.WebClientApplication   : Started WebClientApplication in 2.446 seconds (JVM running for 3.272)
Testing with Webclient
2020-05-16 16:32:20.680 DEBUG 9928 --- [  restartedMain] r.netty.resources.DefaultLoopEpoll       : Default Epoll support : false
2020-05-16 16:32:20.688 DEBUG 9928 --- [  restartedMain] r.netty.resources.DefaultLoopKQueue      : Default KQueue support : false
2020-05-16 16:32:20.893 DEBUG 9928 --- [  restartedMain] r.n.resources.PooledConnectionProvider   : Creating a new client pool [PoolFactory {maxConnections=500, pendingAcquireMaxCount=-1, pendingAcquireTimeout=45000, maxIdleTime=-1, maxLifeTime=-1, metricsEnabled=false}] for [localhost:8080]
Testing with RestTemplate
2020-05-16 16:32:21.369 DEBUG 9928 --- [ctor-http-nio-1] r.n.resources.PooledConnectionProvider   : [id: 0x77afe9df] Created a new pooled channel, now 1 active connections and 0 inactive connections
2020-05-16 16:32:21.440 DEBUG 9928 --- [ctor-http-nio-1] reactor.netty.channel.BootstrapHandlers  : [id: 0x77afe9df] Initialized pipeline DefaultChannelPipeline{(BootstrapHandlers$BootstrapInitializerHandler#0 = reactor.netty.channel.BootstrapHandlers$BootstrapInitializerHandler), (PooledConnectionProvider$PooledConnectionAllocator$PooledConnectionInitializer#0 = reactor.netty.resources.PooledConnectionProvider$PooledConnectionAllocator$PooledConnectionInitializer), (reactor.left.httpCodec = io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpClientCodec), (reactor.left.decompressor = io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpContentDecompressor), (reactor.right.reactiveBridge = reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler)}
2020-05-16 16:32:21.457 DEBUG 9928 --- [ctor-http-nio-1] r.n.resources.PooledConnectionProvider   : [id: 0x77afe9df, L:/127.0.0.1:52476 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:8080] Registering pool release on close event for channel
2020-05-16 16:32:21.458 DEBUG 9928 --- [ctor-http-nio-1] r.n.resources.PooledConnectionProvider   : [id: 0x77afe9df, L:/127.0.0.1:52476 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:8080] Channel connected, now 1 active connections and 0 inactive connections
2020-05-16 16:32:21.459 DEBUG 9928 --- [ctor-http-nio-1] r.n.resources.PooledConnectionProvider   : [id: 0x77afe9df, L:/127.0.0.1:52476 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:8080] onStateChange(PooledConnection{channel=[id: 0x77afe9df, L:/127.0.0.1:52476 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:8080]}, [connected])
2020-05-16 16:32:21.473 DEBUG 9928 --- [ctor-http-nio-1] r.n.resources.PooledConnectionProvider   : [id: 0x77afe9df, L:/127.0.0.1:52476 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:8080] onStateChange(GET{uri=/, connection=PooledConnection{channel=[id: 0x77afe9df, L:/127.0.0.1:52476 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:8080]}}, [configured])
2020-05-16 16:32:21.475 DEBUG 9928 --- [ctor-http-nio-1] r.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect    : [id: 0x77afe9df, L:/127.0.0.1:52476 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:8080] Handler is being applied: {uri=http://localhost:8080/api/test, method=GET}
2020-05-16 16:32:21.477 DEBUG 9928 --- [ctor-http-nio-1] r.n.resources.PooledConnectionProvider   : [id: 0x77afe9df, L:/127.0.0.1:52476 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:8080] onStateChange(GET{uri=/api/test, connection=PooledConnection{channel=[id: 0x77afe9df, L:/127.0.0.1:52476 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:8080]}}, [request_prepared])
2020-05-16 16:32:21.517 DEBUG 9928 --- [ctor-http-nio-1] r.n.resources.PooledConnectionProvider   : [id: 0x77afe9df, L:/127.0.0.1:52476 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:8080] onStateChange(GET{uri=/api/test, connection=PooledConnection{channel=[id: 0x77afe9df, L:/127.0.0.1:52476 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:8080]}}, [request_sent])
OK
2020-05-16 16:32:26.476 DEBUG 9928 --- [ctor-http-nio-1] r.n.resources.PooledConnectionProvider   : [id: 0x77afe9df, L:/127.0.0.1:52476 ! R:localhost/127.0.0.1:8080] Channel closed, now 0 active connections and 0 inactive connections
2020-05-16 16:32:26.476 DEBUG 9928 --- [ctor-http-nio-1] r.n.resources.PooledConnectionProvider   : [id: 0x77afe9df, L:/127.0.0.1:52476 ! R:localhost/127.0.0.1:8080] onStateChange(GET{uri=/api/test, connection=PooledConnection{channel=[id: 0x77afe9df, L:/127.0.0.1:52476 ! R:localhost/127.0.0.1:8080]}}, [response_incomplete])
2020-05-16 16:32:26.491  WARN 9928 --- [ctor-http-nio-1] r.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect    : [id: 0x77afe9df, L:/127.0.0.1:52476 ! R:localhost/127.0.0.1:8080] The connection observed an error

reactor.netty.http.client.PrematureCloseException: Connection prematurely closed BEFORE response

2020-05-16 16:32:26.491  WARN 9928 --- [ctor-http-nio-1] reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive        : [id: 0x77afe9df, L:/127.0.0.1:52476 ! R:localhost/127.0.0.1:8080] An exception has been observed post termination

reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: reactor.netty.http.client.PrematureCloseException: Connection prematurely closed BEFORE response
Caused by: reactor.netty.http.client.PrematureCloseException: Connection prematurely closed BEFORE response
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ Request to GET http://localhost:8080/api/test [DefaultWebClient]
Stack trace:
```

I am using tomcat in the  REST API server :

Logs of server are also attached:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.3.0.RELEASE)

2020-05-16 16:36:25.661  INFO 6812 --- [  restartedMain] c.w.s.WebClientDemoServerApplication     : Starting WebClientDemoServerApplication on DESKTOP-054O660 with PID 6812 (D:\eclipse-jee-2019-09-R-win32-x86_64\workspace\WebClientDemoServer\server\target\classes started by Akshay in D:\eclipse-jee-2019-09-R-win32-x86_64\workspace\WebClientDemoServer\server)
2020-05-16 16:36:25.661  INFO 6812 --- [  restartedMain] c.w.s.WebClientDemoServerApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-05-16 16:36:25.723  INFO 6812 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2020-05-16 16:36:25.723  INFO 6812 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2020-05-16 16:36:26.942  INFO 6812 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-05-16 16:36:26.955  INFO 6812 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-05-16 16:36:26.955  INFO 6812 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.35]
2020-05-16 16:36:27.049  INFO 6812 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-05-16 16:36:27.049  INFO 6812 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1326 ms
2020-05-16 16:36:27.283  INFO 6812 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-05-16 16:36:27.455 DEBUG 6812 --- [  restartedMain] reactor.netty.tcp.TcpResources           : [http] resources will use the default LoopResources: DefaultLoopResources {prefix=reactor-http, daemon=true, selectCount=4, workerCount=4}
2020-05-16 16:36:27.471 DEBUG 6812 --- [  restartedMain] reactor.netty.tcp.TcpResources           : [http] resources will use the default ConnectionProvider: reactor.netty.resources.PooledConnectionProvider@7f6d3bcb
2020-05-16 16:36:27.487  INFO 6812 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2020-05-16 16:36:27.533  INFO 6812 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2020-05-16 16:36:27.549  INFO 6812 --- [  restartedMain] c.w.s.WebClientDemoServerApplication     : Started WebClientDemoServerApplication in 2.36 seconds (JVM running for 3.545)
2020-05-16 16:36:39.781  INFO 6812 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-05-16 16:36:39.789  INFO 6812 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-05-16 16:36:39.791  INFO 6812 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 2 ms
Test Request Started
Test Request Started
Test Request Ended
Test Request Ended
```

Comment: You are most likely hitting a connection-timeout on the server, which will close the connection prematurely.

Comment: There is no exception on the server side. Also what surprised me is when I increase the sleep time to 1 minute, everything goes as expected. Is anything I am missing in my code.

Comment: Yeah. That is strange. I am not seeing anything else really obvious wrong

Comment: I am using JDK 1.8.0_231, shall I change it

Comment: I don't think it is an issue with the JDK. Did you try to call the endpoint with some API Client app (like Insomnia or Postman)? This could help to determine if it is a problem on the client or the server.

Comment: I am giving it a try by postman. However, why does call by spring Rest Template never fails

Comment: No issues from postman

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213994/discussion-between-akshay-and-puelo).

Answer (score 9):

For future readers. I had a similar issue, I've fixed it by adding **ReactorClientHttpConnector** to Webclient creation process.

BEFORE:

```
        this.webClient = WebClient.builder()
            .baseUrl(url)
            .build();
```

AFTER:

```
        this.webClient = WebClient.builder()
            .baseUrl(url)
            .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(HttpClient.newConnection().compress(true)))
            .build();
```

Spring Boot version: 2.3.6

Reactor netty version: 0.9.14

Good luck!

Comment: Man this is a life saver. I was using WebClient with Spring Batch parallel processing and was getting this error for every executor I had. And I tried pretty much everything I could find over Google. Nothing worked but this Amazing Thing did the trick. God bless you and SO community.....for making IT happen.

Comment: I think that this configures the client to open a new connection for each request, basically by-passing any pooling and re-use, which may backfire later.
Maybe it's worth finding out the real issue and tuning the connection parameters on both sides.