# How to set a long read timeout for Spring WebClient (to avoid PrematureCloseException)

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception, netty, spring-webclient

I have a Spring Boot application with a Spring WebClient sending requests to another Spring-Boot application (Spring-Boot 2.7.14 and Spring WebFlux 5.3.29)

```
    WebClient.Builder wcBuilder = WebClient.builder()
            .exchangeStrategies(ExchangeStrategies.builder()
                    .codecs(configurer -> configurer
                            .defaultCodecs()
                            .maxInMemorySize(MAX_RESPONSE_SIZE_MB * BYTES_PER_MB))
                    .build());

    WebClient webClient = wcBuilder
            .baseUrl(url)
            .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.USER_AGENT, "MyClient v1.0")
            .build();                        
                    
    webClient.post()
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            .bodyValue(someData)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(MyClass.class);
```

Some requests require a lot of processing and those can take about 60 - 90 seconds to complete. My problem is that these requests always return the error

```
org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException: 
Connection prematurely closed BEFORE response; nested exception is reactor.netty.http.client.PrematureCloseException: Connection prematurely closed BEFORE response
```

after 50-51 seconds. To fix that I tried adding a `ReactorClientHttpConnector` as also suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65846482/741249) and set a timeout

```
    WebClient.Builder wcBuilder = WebClient.builder()
            .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(HttpClient.create()
                    .responseTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(TIMEOUT))))
    ...
```

When setting the timeout to 40 seconds I get a slightly different error after 40-41 seconds (`io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutException`), so the setting is working. However when I set a timeout of 90 or 120 seconds I still get the PrematureCloseException after 50 seconds. I looked into other settings I may be missing and also tried using a ConnectionProvider and various other options, e.g.

```
ConnectionProvider provider =
            ConnectionProvider.builder("custom")
                    .maxConnections(100)
                    .maxIdleTime(Duration.ofSeconds(TIMEOUT))
                    .maxLifeTime(Duration.ofSeconds(TIMEOUT)).build();

    WebClient.Builder wcBuilder = WebClient.builder()
            .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(HttpClient.create(provider)
                    .option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true)
                    .option(EpollChannelOption.TCP_KEEPIDLE, 300)
                    .option(EpollChannelOption.TCP_KEEPINTVL, 60)
                    .option(EpollChannelOption.TCP_KEEPCNT, 8)
                    .doOnConnected(conn -> conn
                            .addHandler(new ReadTimeoutHandler(TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)))
                    .responseTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(TIMEOUT))))
    ...
```

but all with the same result. What setting am I missing here?

I think the issue is client-side because I had the same issue earlier when talking to a different (Python-based) server. Also I see no errors on the server side and the server always finishes processing as normal.

**ADDENDUM:**
Note that my problem is different from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56957057/prematurecloseexception-connection-prematurely-closed) because I didn't even start processing and am waiting for the data from the server.
What I see happening with `wiretap(true)` is:

```
15:44:31.670 [reactor-http-epoll-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient:145 - [...] READ COMPLETE
15:44:31.682 [reactor-http-epoll-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.resources.PooledConnectionProvider:259 - [...] Channel closed, now: 0 active connections, 0 inactive connections and 0 pending acquire requests.
15:44:31.683 [reactor-http-epoll-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.ReactorNetty:259 - [] Non Removed handler: ReadTimeoutHandler, context: ChannelHandlerContext(ReadTimeoutHandler, [...]), pipeline: DefaultChannelPipeline{(reactor.left.sslHandler = io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler), (reactor.left.loggingHandler = reactor.netty.transport.logging.ReactorNettyLoggingHandler), (reactor.left.httpCodec = io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpClientCodec), (reactor.left.responseTimeoutHandler = io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutHandler), (ReadTimeoutHandler = io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutHandler), (reactor.right.reactiveBridge = reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler)}
15:44:31.683 [reactor-http-epoll-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.ReactorNetty:259 - [...] Non Removed handler: reactor.left.responseTimeoutHandler, context: ChannelHandlerContext(reactor.left.responseTimeoutHandler, [...]), pipeline: DefaultChannelPipeline{(reactor.left.sslHandler = io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler), (reactor.left.loggingHandler = reactor.netty.transport.logging.ReactorNettyLoggingHandler), (reactor.left.httpCodec = io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpClientCodec), (reactor.left.responseTimeoutHandler = io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutHandler), (ReadTimeoutHandler = io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutHandler), (reactor.right.reactiveBridge = reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler)}
15:44:31.686 [reactor-http-epoll-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient:145 - [...] USER_EVENT: SslCloseCompletionEvent(java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException)
15:44:31.688 [reactor-http-epoll-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient:145 - [...] INACTIVE
15:44:31.688 [reactor-http-epoll-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider:259 - [...] onStateChange(POST{uri=..., connection=PooledConnection{channel=[...]}}, [response_incomplete])
15:44:31.694 [reactor-http-epoll-2] WARN reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect:304 - [...] The connection observed an error
reactor.netty.http.client.PrematureCloseException: Connection prematurely closed BEFORE response
15:44:31.716 [reactor-http-epoll-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient:145 - [...] UNREGISTERED
15:44:32.216 [Connection evictor] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager:448 - Closing expired connections
15:44:32.216 [Connection evictor] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager:441 - Closing connections idle longer than 50000 MILLISECONDS
```

So there is an Apache PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager that kills connections after 50 seconds. From the timestamps of the logs it looks like it's Netty that is closing the connection before that, but perhaps the timestamps are inaccurate?

Comment: Hmm. Probably I'm missing something but not sure why Apache `PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager` is used here instead of Netty implementation.